# Are real-time linux extensions obsolete?

Tags: linux, kernel, real-time

Do the new real-time and low latency patches from Ingo Molnar render previous real-time extensions for Linux (such as RTAI, Xenomai) obsolete?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: @MDCore: this is a Linux kernel source code patch question, and is definitely a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it to me, although I've not endeavoured to build a real-time system on Linux (yet).  RTAI look like APIs.  POSIX.4 would be similar (and of course *infinitely superior* in my humble opinion as the former vice-chair of that committee and author of the book :) .

Molnar's work looks to me as if it is designed to actually provide real-time *performance* to Linux.  So to write a real, real-time application, you're probably talking about (1) using real-time APIs as well as the standard *nix calls, and (2) building your application very carefully, taking account of techniques mentioned on the [Real-Time Linux Wiki](http://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).  So in general, I'd say you need both.  And probably even more than those two!